# Any MVC 3 tutorials on *Real World* developement situations?

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC total noobe here but long time web developer - 10 + years. The tutorials for MVC 3 (and earlier versions) are great but as usual they lack a ton for real on the job type scenarios.

For example, how often do you find yourself in a situation where you are going to create a new database from scratch with no stored procs so that you could actually use EF Code-First. I don't know about you but in my career it has been NEVER.

The usual story is that you are creating a new app or enhancing an existing app with new functionality that will connect to an existing very mature database with tons of stored procs, user defined functions and views and you are required either by management or time restrictions to use it all. And of course you may get to create some new tables but they usually will have joins to existing tables or in the least your app will have to query existing tables for some of the data.

To see a tutorial based on that scenario would be WORTH IT'S WEIGHT IN GOLD. Especially the stored procedure scenario.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: I guess this sort of thing is hard to write a tutorial about, it's comes down to your skill and experience as a developer to establish how your newly learned coding techniques can be applied to your legacy data model / application

Comment: @Andy - I can't understand why it would be any harder to write a tutorial based on real world coding scenarios but then I don't write many tutorials either. The point is if MS want a lot of main stream developers to adapt a technology they should consider this. I have heard a lot of devs echo this same thing and not just about MVC - but Silverlight and many other MS technologies.

Comment: Why are you conflating ORMs with MVC?

Comment: @Kirk> It's a common complaint that I've seen.  He's not conflating the ORMs & MVC so much as he's complaining that the MVC tutorials all assume that you're on a greenfield project, while most projects aren't greenfield.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the earlier examples (e.g. the original [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx)) were based on either Linq to Sql or Entity Framework (without CodeFirst). Since CodeFirst is the 'new hotness' most of the latest examples use it.

The interesting part of the question, though, is that it highlights an important point:  "it doesn't matter".  Your data access strategy (EF, EF code first, NHibernate, L2S, raw SQL) is totally irrelevant to MVC.  By that I don't mean it's unimportant, I mean that MVC doesn't place any constraints on you at all in that regard.

You will generally (in a well-designed MVC app) pass your controllers interfaces which let them call data access methods of various sorts (or perhaps another layer of indirection with services that do other things before hitting the storage layer).  The implementation of the data access, if it is using an ORM like EF or Nhibernate, will then have mechanisms for you to either use a query syntax of some sort (e.g. LINQ) or to call stored procedures (possible in all major ORMs that Iv'e used) or to push raw SQL if hte situation calls for it.

Comment: Very good point and it does underline my question. All the new tuts for MVC 3 use EF Code First. It would be nice to see some that do not. In real life IMHO EF Code first might be nice for proof of concept and modeling - but for production - I can't really see it.

Comment: Well, that's why it's still in CTP. That said, my point stands that you should be able to follow the tuts and simply insert your own Model logic using the same data access strategies you're used to.  The only parts of MVC that should be new to you are the V and the C.